# Can we achieve parent child relationship with CssSelectors in Selenium

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, css-selectors, webdriver

Is parent child relationship valid for cssSelector as well in selenium
Example-
This X-path is valid:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='gb_ke gb_i gb_Kg gb_Ag']/div[2]/a")).click();
```

But this cssSelector is not:

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div[class*='gb_ke gb_i gb_Kg gb_Ag']/div[2]/a")).click();
```

It gives the error:

```
An invalid or illegal selector was specified
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To start with [xpath](/questions/tagged/xpath) and [css-selectors](/questions/tagged/css-selectors) follows different syntax.

The equivalent *cssSelector* locator for the *xpath*:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='gb_ke gb_i gb_Kg gb_Ag']/div[2]/a")).click();
```

Can be either of the following as per the prevalent *HTML DOM*:

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div.gb_ke.gb_i.gb_Kg.gb_Ag > div:nth-of-type(2) > a")).click();
```

Or

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div.gb_ke.gb_i.gb_Kg.gb_Ag > div:nth-child(2) > a")).click();
```

Answer (score 2):

CSS selectors and XPath selectors have a different syntax.

Your xpath is `By.xpath("//div[@class='gb_ke gb_i gb_Kg gb_Ag']/div[2]/a")`

and you should update your CSS accordingly, e.g.

CSS `By.cssSelector("div[class*='gb_ke gb_i gb_Kg gb_Ag'] div:nth-child(2) a")`